# RMarkdown to beamer with xtable and longtable option

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr, beamer

**Reproducable example:**

I am knitting a `.rmd` document which should show a table of the `airquality` data frame to a beamer pdf document in RStudio.

.rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes: 
      in_header: mystyle.sty
---

## Page 1

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(airquality), comment=F, tabular.environment='longtable',floating=FALSE)

```
````

As the data frame is quite long I am using the `tabular.environment='long table'` option as described [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fxtable%2Fvignettes%2FxtableGallery.pdf&ei=8XsVVL_5CYiCPbWkgYAE&usg=AFQjCNEbM2py7DDsVhnX9twxFN-WSPWUZA&sig2=coPpfcVH9t--iu5g7tI-IA&bvm=bv.75097201,d.ZWU). I am importing in the the `.rmd` header via `mystyle.sty` the `longtable` package, so that the LaTex compilation is prepared.

mystyle.sty:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

**Problem:**

The .pdf output is generated without error, but unfortunately the `longtable` does not work. There's just one page and the table has not been wrapped.

[image]

**Question:**

The target was to get multiple frames (pages) automatically generated fitting the data frame. Any solution to achieve this target?

Comment: I think you'll find answers on the tex site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/same-header-on-different-slides-with-beamer-and-longtable http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/is-it-possible-to-force-beamer-to-automatically-create-frames-for-the-excessive

Comment: How does your comment provide a solution to the problem? Can you please be more specific and provide a code which solves the reproducable example.

Comment: It does not provide an answer, that is why it is a comment not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can add the latex package to your preamble in the YAML front matter:

```
header-includes:
     - \usepackage{longtable}
```

This is the only thing I am doing differently and it does work for me.

Also, you might want to add the following options:

```
,include.colnames=TRUE, include.rownames=FALSE
```

The first option will repeat the header on each page, the second option will not show the row numbers in the first row.

The problem I'm still having is that it seems to render a { before my table and a } after it.

Comment: If the {} thing happens to you you can redirect the print into an object and then use regular expressions to remove the first and the last character.